# During an iteration print the whole list but the current index

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iteration

So I was working on my top-down rpg project and I made some changes in the movement of npcs.
More specifically before I move any npc I first check whether its next position is taken basically.

So obviously in order to achieve that, I need for every npc to check the current positions of all **other** npcs.

So my question is which is the best pythonic way to iterate through a **list of objects** and in every iteration access the whole list **but** the list's element with the current index.

A way I thought of was:

```
for index,element in enumerate(my_list):
    print my_list[:index] + my_list[index + 1:]
```

But I would like to know any other possible ways :)
Cheers and although I checked thoroughly I couldn't find a similar question, so feel free to inform me for any other possible duplicates!

Alex

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this approach

Comment: Why do you need to exclude the current NPC from the list anyway? If it's moving at all, its new position won't be the same as its old position, so what harm is there in leaving it in the list?

Comment: Thats good to hear njk2 I was just thinking my way may be inefficient for a big list. Kevin my thinking is that if I leave the current npc in the list, the method that checks the positions of an npc with the others would always include a check of an npc with itself so basically it wouldn't allow it to move

Comment: I mean how many npcs are you going to have? computers are pretty zippy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your approach is pretty readable, but inefficient for large lists(it builds list again everytime).

I'd probably use a simple for loop:

```
for i, j in enumerate(my_list):
    for elem in (v for k, v in enumerate(my_list) if k != i):
        print elem,
```

Edit: For performance, you can use `itertools.ifilter`, which doesn't build a list. On Python 3, built-in `filter` behaves the same.

Comment: I think that approach is way better than mine! Thanks utdemir! I'll accept as soon as I can

Comment: Sorry, I thought I removed enumeration, missed that piece.

Comment: Now I'm filtering by position. But that'd work with primitive types too, since they're also objects. See `(3).__eq__(3)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for both memory efficient and fast solution then you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)  with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) here. This is going to be faster than @utdemir's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944093/846892) because in filtering step no Python for-loop is involved:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

def islice_ashwch(my_list):
    for i, j in enumerate(my_list):
        for elem in chain(islice(my_list, i), islice(my_list, i+1, None)):
            pass

def gen_utd(my_list):
    #https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944093/846892
    for i, j in enumerate(my_list):
        for elem in (v for k, v in enumerate(my_list) if k != i):
            pass
```

Timing comparison:

```
In [6]: lst = range(100)

In [7]: %timeit gen_utd(lst)
1000 loops, best of 3: 680 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit islice_ashwch(lst)
1000 loops, best of 3: 204 µs per loop

In [9]: lst = range(1000)

In [10]: %timeit gen_utd(lst)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.3 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit islice_ashwch(lst)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think that a deleted solutions was more elegant: `>>> for noindex in range(len(my_list)) :
...     print([elem for index, elem in enumerate(my_list) if index != noindex])`

Comment: @LucasMalor OP's solution is far better than that, if there's no issue with creating a new list in memory then why not use simple slicing which is blazingly fast.